# Which schemes does NSURL / NSURLRequest / NSURLConnection understand?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Apple says, NSURL is developed using RFC 1738 (and some others).

Now RFC 1738 specifies only that an web URL has a scheme and a scheme specific part.

I want to know all the schemes which NSURL understands. And because I use it with NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection (the so called "URL Loader System"), I must know all the schemes which these understand.

Why? Because I just want to know. Apple does not go into detail about it in the documentation, the just say the comply to RFC 1738. That tells a lot and also nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSURL` "supports" any scheme, because it knows nothing about how to use the scheme in question. It is just a wrapper around the concept of a URL.

Likewise, `NSURLRequest` knows no more, but it does have capability to store extra information which could be protocol-specific.

`NSURLConnection` is where you start getting more protocol-specific. `NSURLConnection` is capable of supporting any URL you throw at it, provided there is a suitable `NSURLProtocol` subclass registered for that. But out of the box, it is *documented* to support `http:`, `https:`, `ftp:` and `file:`. You can test it with a quick `+canHandleRequest:` call.

Empirically, the system supports `data:` URLs too. I have filed radar://problem/13649313 with Apple asking them to document this.

Answer (score 4):

The built-in URL protocols can handle the schemes `http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, `about`, and `data`.

You can define your own protocols to make the NSURL system automatically handle new schemes using the `NSURLProtocol` class.